# Change image on json property when appending template

Tags: javascript, json, this, mustache

An image can have [1,2,3,4] states (placeholder, processing, accepted, rejected) in a JSON format. I am figuring out a function to check the property and select the right image to place in the Mustache HTML.

I tried the following:

```
for (let i=0;i<101;i++) {
        var output = Mustache.render(template, view[i]);
        $('#entryTable tbody').append(output);

        if (view[i].status == 2) {
            this.getElementById('picture1').src= 'img/analyzing.png';
        } else if (view[i].status == 3) {
            this.getElementById('picture1').src= 'img/irrelevant.png';
            console.log(this)
        } else if (view [i].status == 4) {
            this.getElementById('picture1').src= 'img/relevant.png';
        }
```

But 'this' refers to the document and not the image -> it changes only the first image (for all entries, repeatedly) that appears.

Next, I tried:

```
 for (let i=0;i<101;i++) {
        var output = Mustache.render(template, view[i]);
        $('#entryTable tbody').append(function() {

//the default image in the template is state 1, hence it checks for state 2 and above

        if (view[i].state == 2) {
            this.getElementById('picture1').src= 'img/analyzing.png';
        } else if (view[i].state == 3) {
            this.getElementById('picture1').src= 'img/irrelevant.png';
            console.log(this)
        } else if (view [i].state == 4) {
            this.getElementById('picture1').src= 'img/relevant.png';
        }

        return output;
});
```

Which seems(?) to work but only appends one entry.

I am not experienced with 'this', how would I get it to the right context/scope to change the entry specific image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
if (view[i].state === 1) {
            $("#entryTable tbody tr .status1").eq(i).attr("src", "img/analyzing.png");
        } else if (view[i].state === 3) {
            $("#entryTable tbody tr .status1").eq(i).attr("src", "img/irrelevant.png");
        } else if (view[i].state === 4) {
            $("#entryTable tbody tr .status1").eq(i).attr("src", "img/relevant.png");
        }
}
```